# How to connect Google Cloud SQL from Google Container Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-sql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using **Kubernetes** to deploy a **Rails application** to **Google Container Engine**.

The database is using **Google Cloud SQL**.

I know the database's ip address and set it into my Kubernetes config file:

```
# web-controller.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    name: web
  name: web-controller
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    name: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: gcr.io/my-project-id/myapp:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: http-server
        env:
          - name: RAILS_ENV
            value: "production"
          - name: DATABASE_URL
            value: "mysql2://[my_username]:[my_password]@[database_ip]/myapp"
```

Then create:

```
$ kubectl create -f web-controller.yml
```

From the pod log I saw:

```
$ kubectl logs web-controller-038dl
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'
...
```

I can see the **LoadBalancer Ingress** ip address from the **Kubernetes UI** page in web service section.

From the **Google Developers Console -> Storage -> SQL**, select the running db and click the link. From **Access Controler -> Authorization -> Authorized Networks**, add a new item and add that IP to there. But the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create the SSL cert like Yu-Ju Hong said, then you would have to tell ruby to use the certificate when connecting something like

http://makandracards.com/makandra/1701-use-ssl-for-amazon-rds-mysql-and-your-rails-app

The bit about:

`sslca: /path/to/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem`

Comment: Thank you. I am using database_url to connect remote mysql. So maybe I should attach that after my url string like: `mysql2://[my_username]:[my_password]@[database_ip]/myapp?sslca=/path/to/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem`

Answer (score 1):

From [Cannot access google cloud SQL from google container engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665843/cannot-access-google-cloud-sql-from-google-container-engine), it seems "using SSL connection with that 0.0.0.0/0 CIDR" is the recommended solution.